# Is there a java10 compatiable version of the javafx gradle plugin?

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I need to run a java application in my gradle build. That application uses reflection, and will not run in java 11. So my gradle JVM needs to be java 10. (A dead end, I know, that's what I'm working on)

But my build configurations currently use the javafx plugin, and all the versions on plugins.gradle.org are built with Java 11 classes, so the plugin won't work with Java 10.
I compiled the javafx plugin for Java 10 with sources from github, but the plugin is configured to use java 11 repositories, so I'd need to figure that out and replace them.

It would save me enormous hassle if there was already a javafx plugin that works with Java 10.

Comment: The [javafx-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin) was created specifically to help developers use JavaFX 11+ since JavaFX was decoupled from the JDK in Java 11. Is there no way to make your application work in Java 11, even with any appropriate `opens` directives and/or `--add-opens` arguments?

Comment: What has reflection to do with not beeing able to use Java 11? In the long run "it would save you enormous hassle" if you would try to solve your real problem and make your code work on Java 11+.

Comment: The tool is third party, and it uses a library that uses sun.*.reflection.* classes which have been removed in java 11. There is no update for that old library. The tool is needed to generate data  needed to build and  run the the 3rd-party application. That stage must be java 10. The new app I'm writing will be java 11, but it will be a hassle to create a build that runs in java 10, stops, is reconfigured for a different JVM, and then is run again.